# How to remote view OSX machine from Fedora with TigerVNC

Tags: linux, fedora, osx, vnc

I understand the I can use VNC protocol for remote viewing.

There is a mac on my network which has VNC enabled. I have downloaded [TigerVNC](https://tigervnc.org/)

```
dnf install tigervnc
```

I get the IP address of host I want to view

```
host hostName
```

And then type `userName@hostIpAddress` into the field in the screen shot and press connect but I'm not able to connect.

[image]
when I press connect I get message

> unable to resolve host by name: Name or service not known.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it from the command terminal. I go to the directory the app is installed in

```
cd /usr/share/applications
```

and then I just can just remove view the using the host name, no need for a user name... just type this into the terminal

```
vncviewer hostName
```

and then I just sign into the user account I want